# RewriteRule translating url to use different php files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the .htaccess file of my PHP application I use one simple rewrite to translate my URLs from:

```
/shop/hats/detroit/
```

to:

```
index.php?url=/shop/hats/detroit/
```

using the following rewrite rule:

```
# Rule 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /repos/nvp/httpdocs/index.php?url=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I would like the following rewrite to work as well:

```
# Rule 2
RewriteRule ^pic/(.*)$ /repos/nvp/httpdocs/get_image.php?pic=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But the two rules are kind of overwriting or conflicting with each other. They work each on their own but not together. How can I use all urls to use Rule 1 and only if url starts with **pic/** to use Rule 2 instead of Rule 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the pattern  `(.*)` matches all uris . 
In order to avoid the rules overriding  ,you need to reorder your rules and  put the specific rules first in order.

```
# specific rules
RewriteRule ^pic/(.*)$ /repos/nvp/httpdocs/get_image.php?pic=$1 [L,QSA]
#catch-all rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /repos/nvp/httpdocs/index.php?url=/$1 [L,QSA]
```